# How to write in Urdu in text editors on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: text-editor, input-language

I want to write Urdu in my text editors in Ubuntu 20.04? However, the language support isnt available officially and the solutions on the web don't seem to work?
I would prefer a phonetic keyboard but anything is fine.

Comment: There is an Urdu (Phonetic) keyboard layout by default. If you install the `ibus-m17n` package and relogin, you'll see yet another Urdu (Phonetic) option.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thankyou very much

Comment: I install ibus-m17n on ubuntu 22.04 but still unable to find english option.
I'm able to see other languages e.g punjabi etc but not Urdu. Don't know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `ibus-m17n` package and re-login. That will make the *Urdu (phonetic (m17n))* input method available.